# lubuntu: How do I run .64 files?

Tags: lubuntu, files, games, programming, development

I have problem with a .64 file I downloaded from the Godot Engine website.
How do I execute this file?

I really have no clue.

Thanks you.

Comment: Open a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T), run the command `file /insert/path/to/file/here.64` and [edit] your question to paste the output there. It will display some information about the file content which may help to find a suitable program to actually view it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please add what you have tried so far. What worked what didn't. Edit your Question and add your findings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First enter a terminal session by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, then use the `cd` command access the directory the file is saved to, such as:

```
cd /path/to/download/directory
```

Then you need to apply the execute permission to the file so that you can run the file:

```
chmod +x Godot_v2.0_alpha_20150930_x11.64
```

Now all you need to do is run the file with:

```
./Godot_v2.0_alpha_20150930_x11.64
```

Comment: Thanks ! I would have never found that out through plain Google search.

Comment: @BreakSilence If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.