# .64 file: Unable to locate program

Tags: software-installation, mount

I just mounted an NTFS partition as my home directory. Unfortunately, I now don't seem to be able to run any programs anymore. I just downloaded a .64 file I'm trying to execute - but ubuntu didn't know what to do with it, I had to manually select "run application".

But it still doesn't work. First, it asks `“NameOfYourPartition” contains software intended to be automatically started. Would you like to run it?`, and when I press "run", the error `Oops! There was a problem running this software. Unable to locate the program` appears.

What should I do? My guess would be that something is wrong with my mounting settings, since it worked before I moved /home to another partition.

Here is the line of the partition in my `/etc/fstab/ file:

```
 /dev/disk/by-uuid/1FCF79B742CF7214 /home/myname auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,user 0 0
```

Edit: I just found ["How to run a .64 file"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/685951/lubuntu-how-do-i-run-64-files) which was featuring the exact same file I am trying to execute - the [Godot game engine](https://godotengine.org/download). If I do what is written there (authorize the file using `chmod +x /file/`), following error appears: `sudo: unable to execute ./file.64: Permission denied`.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `source /etc/bash.bashrc` and then run your program 
or 
use `/bin/sh <your program>`
You need some configuration files by default that bash uses. You can try copying these to your current home dir from your previous home dir.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! But I found a solution. I had to add the exec flag to my mounting settings. After that, double-clicking worked perfectly fine.

Comment: @Nearoo great...

Answer (score 0):

It really is a mounting problem. Add the `exec` flag to the mount in `/etc/fstab/` and it will work.